# Check if camera is available

Tags: android, ios, camera, cordova, windows-phone

I want to check if a camera is available on the device before opening the camera interface. Is there a method like "isCameraAvailable()" method in phonegap ? or a trick to do it ? in a future release maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box I'm afraid. For iOS, you could check the target platform (as iOS devices modifications are small in number), so a simple check through device.platform to see if it's an old iPod/iPad that has no camera would suffice.

For Android, you would have to go with a plug-in. Something in the lines of:

```
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        //Camera it is ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do it within the phonegap api. The easiest way would be to create a simple plugin. Here's an android example:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#detect-camera

https://github.com/Airblader/FeatureDetector

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone you can read [this very well explained article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx):
PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) is the method that you searching for ;)